# GMailApp rateMax - service invoked too fast

Tags: google-apps-script

I published a Google Apps Script as a WebApp, but sometimes the users using the script run into:

`Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line XXX)`

The exception tells me to slow it down with a `Utitlities.sleep(1000)`, however before doing that I'd like to know what exactly the maximum rate is. The only documentation I can find about this is the quota page, but this says:
`GMail Read:    10000 / day`
and my script is far away from 10000 reads.
Does anybody know what `rateMax` exactly refers to?

Update: The code causing this is the following (gets called via XHR):

```
add = function(form) {
// [...]

messageId = (_ref = form.msgId) != null ? _ref : form.messageId;
if (!messageId || !(message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId))) {
  throw ErrorCodes.INVALID_MESSAGE_ID;
}

// [...]

thread = GmailApp.getThreadById(message.getThread().getId());
if (String(form.archive) === "true") {
  thread.moveToArchive();
}

// [...]

addLabel(LABEL_BASE, thread);
addLabel(LABEL_OUTBOX, thread);
};

getLabel = function(name, create) {
var _ref;
return (_ref = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name)) != null ? _ref : (create ? GmailApp.createLabel(name) : void 0);
};

addLabel = function(name, thread) {
var _ref;
if ((_ref = this.getLabel(name, true)) != null) {
  _ref.addToThread(thread);
}
};
```

`// [...]` denotes removed code from the sample that does not do calls to the GMail API.

Answer (score 0):

Were you checking attachments, or doing something else? There was a bug that should be fixed now that triggered this when loading attachments.

Comment: Nope, only a simple call to `GmailApp.getMessageById`.

Comment: Ok, in general more than 10 or so requests per second will trigger that but I am frankly surprised to see it happening. Can you post a longer snippet of the code that causes the error?

Comment: I added it to the question - are all the calls to GmailApp counted? I can see 8 happening within a short time then.

Comment: No, only some calls are counted. I'm going to take a closer look at your snippet and see if I can find the issue.